# Отображение степени

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста как отобразить значения переменной не как решенное выражение а как число в степени
2², 2³, и так далее.....
А то у меня питон возводит в степень)

```
dlina=int(input("Какова длина списка: "))
nums=[2**k for k in range(dlina)]
print(nums)
```

Какова длина списка: 10

```
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512]
```

Нужно чтобы список был `[2², 2³, ...]` такого формата.
Знаю это учебное задание и я его решил, но как записывать степени чтобы они отображались а не возводились, в моем учебнике не написано.
Спасибо за понимание.

Comment: а где вы хотите выводить в таком виде? вы же понимаете, что в том же notepad у вас так не получится?  вам html код сформировать? можно выводить в текстовом виде только в псевдовиде, например так `2^0, 2^1, 2^2` и т.п.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, Вам всё-таки не нужно выводить степени в формате `2ⁿ`. Но ради спортивного интереса приведу свой вариант.

Современные версии Python используют для кодирования символов [Unicode](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4), соответственно Вы можете использовать [возможности](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) Unicode для представления надстрочных символов.

Часть таблицы кодирования для надстрочных цифр выглядит следующим образом:

[image: Таблица Unicode]

Зная код, Вы можете сформировать нужный символ с помощью функции [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr):

```py
chr(0x00B9)  # ¹
```

Также можно [использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type) их [имена](https://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/NamesList.txt):

```py
f'\N{SUPERSCRIPT ONE}'  # ¹
```

Но легче всего сохранить их в список и получать по индексу:

```py
['⁰', '¹', '²', '³', '⁴', '⁵', '⁶', '⁷', '⁸', '⁹']
```

---

**P.S.:** Если Вы попробуете сформировать список этим способом, то получите вывод вида `['2²', '2³', ...]`. Он отличается от желаемого Вами, так как репрезентация строк включает в себя одинарные кавычки. Для того чтобы изменить репрезентацию, Вы можете создать собственный класс списка. Но реализация этого поведения выходит за рамки моего ответа.

Comment: разве что сделать join, тогда кавычки будут в начале и в конце: '[...]'